# Is SageMaker Distributed Data-Parallel (SMDDP) supported for keras models?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

Is SageMaker Distributed Data-Parallel (SMDDP) supported for keras models?

In documentation it says "SageMaker distributed data parallel is adaptable to TensorFlow training scripts composed of tf core modules except tf.keras modules. SageMaker distributed data parallel does not support TensorFlow with Keras implementation." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-parallel-modify-sdp.html

But inside the training script and how to modify it, I can see the tf.keras and tf.keras.model is used. https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/sdp_versions/v1.0.0/smd_data_parallel_tensorflow.html

Answer (score 1):

`tf.keras.Sequential` model is usable. However, not all other keras submodules are available yet. This may have changed over the subsequent version releases v1.4 and v1.5